# Alphabet sorting for Column headers

Tags: apex, javascript, salesforcedx, list-view

Im trying to create a customize list view in my component that have the same function as a normal listview column headers => when you click on the header, the list will change in to alphabetical order or the otherway around. 
I tried to search for the layout/function on lightningdesign website but couldn't find any information so I guess I have to code it from the start. 
Im using Apex to generate a list of projects and JS to push it to the html layout.

Everything is done except the toggle function when user click on the column headers. 
Please help. 
Below is the example code:

HTML

```
<lightning-datatable class="slds-scrollable_none slds-table_striped" 
                    key-field="id" 
                    data={data} 
                    columns={columns} 
                    onrowaction={handleRowAction}
                    hide-checkbox-column > 
                </lightning-datatable>
```

Answer (score 2):

There *is* some coding involved to get this running but you shouldn't need to start from scratch. You'll need to update your columns array so that at least one column is sortable (`"sortable": true`), then set the `sortedBy` attribute on your datatable with the name of the column that the table is sorted by when the component loads.

From the `lightning-datatable` [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-datatable/documentation):

> To enable sorting of row data by a column label, set `sortable` to `true`
>   for the column on which you want to enable sorting. Set `sortedBy` to
>   match the `fieldName` attribute on the column. Clicking a column header
>   sorts rows by ascending order unless the `defaultSortDirection` is
>   changed, and clicking it subsequently reverses the order. Handle the
>   `onsort` event handler to update the table with the new column index and
>   sort direction.
>
> Here's an example of the method that's called by the onsort event
>   handler.

```js
// The method onsort event handler
updateColumnSorting(event) {
    var fieldName = event.detail.fieldName;
    var sortDirection = event.detail.sortDirection;
    // assign the latest attribute with the sorted column fieldName and sorted direction
    this.sortedBy = fieldName;
    this.sortedDirection = sortDirection;
    this.data = this.sortData(fieldName, sortDirection);
}
```

Comment: hi there,thanks for your help, I did all of that but every time I click on the header my lightning-datatable disappear ! any idea on why that might happen?

Comment: My assumption is there is a data issue that is causing the table to not render, or there is an error in the sorting function. Two things you can try. First, put a debugger statement at the beginning of your sort function to ensure that the method is being entered and then step through it to see if there are any exceptions. Second, you can try using dummy data with your table to see if it works properly. If it does, there's likely an issue with your original dataset that you will need to correct.

Answer (score 0):

Below is my standard sort algorithm for a LWC. I hope this helps.

```
@track sortBy
@track sortDirection
@track data

handleSortData(event){
        this.sortBy = event.detail.fieldName;
        this.sortDirection = event.detail.sortDirection;
        console.log(event);
        this.sortData(event.detail.fieldName, event.detail.sortDirection);

    };
    sortData(fieldName, direction){
        let parseData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.accounts));
        console.log(`parse data = ${parseData}`);
        let keyvalue = (a) => {
            return a[fieldName];
        };
        let isReverse = direction === 'asc' ? 1 : -1;
        //sort data
        parseData.sort((x, y) => {
            x = keyvalue(x) ? keyvalue(x) : '';
            y= keyvalue(y) ? keyvalue(y) : '';

            return isReverse * ((x > y) - (y > x));
        });
        this.data = parseData;

    }
```

You want your markup to look something like this

```
 <lightning-datatable key-field="accountId" columns={columns}
                                     data={accounts}
                                     hide-checkbox-column="true"
                                     sorted-by={sortBy}
                                     sorted-direction={sortDirection}
                                     onsort={handleSortData}>

</lightning-datatable>
```

Comment: hi there,thanks for your help, I did all of that but every time I click on the header my lightning-datatable disappear ! any idea on why that might happen?